# Polymer 3: How to implement two way data binding for radio input

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x

I'm trying to understand/implement two way attribute binding in a Polymer 3 web component. I've got the following code:

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

 class CustomInputComponent extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return html`        
        <div>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ratings}}">
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="group" 
                       id="item_{{item.id}}" 
                       value="{{item.checked}}" 
                       checked$="{{item.checked}}">                
            </template>
        </div>`;
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            ratings: {
                type: Array,
                value: [
                    { id: 1, checked: true },
                    { id: 2, checked: false }
                ]
            }
        };
    }
}
window.customElements.define('custom-input-component', CustomInputComponent);
```

As you can see, I have defined a Array property containing a default list of values. This property is a model from which I want to render a radio group. The initial state looks good. But when I click on the unchecked input, the DOM elements don't update correctly.

[image: First element is checked although I clicked the second one and the browser also displays that.]

I'd bet I'm missing something really simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main things are:

- You are binding to the `checked` attribute (`$=`), however I don't think radio inputs dynamically update their `checked` attribute. AFAICT, the `checked` *property* is what changes when the input gets selected.
- Also, native `<input type="radio">` inputs will only fire their `change` and `input` events when they are selected, not when they are de-selected. Polymer relies on events to trigger property effects like data bindings; this means that an upwards data binding (from the input to your custom element) will only get processed when the `checked` property on an input changes from `false` to `true`. Effectively, once `ratings[n].checked` becomes true, it will never be made false because Polymer has no way to know that this has occurred.

  Incidentally, to perform two-way binding on a native HTML element, [you would also need to include an annotation for the event that the radio input fires when it is selected](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#two-way-native). So if you did want to capture the changes on selection, it'd be something like `checked="{{item.checked::change}}"`.

A couple of options:

- Use [`paper-radio-button`s](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-button) inside a [`paper-radio-group`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group) instead of native `<input>`s. These elements behave well for two-way data binding.
- Listen for the change when a new item gets checked, and manually update `ratings[n].checked` to `false` for the previously selected item.

A couple more things about your code

- (I don't think this is anything to do with your current problem, but it will help avoid future problems) when initializing a default value for an object or array property in a Polymer element, [remember to use a function](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values) so that each element instance gets its own unique array or object. E.g.:

  `ratings: {
      type: Array,
        value: function(){ 
          return [
           { id: 1, checked: true },
           { id: 2, checked: false }
          ];
        }
     }`
- Normally I think, you wouldn't want to change the *values* of your radio inputs. Conventionally, when the `<form>` containing a radio input group is submitted, the `value` on the radio input that is currently `checked` gets included with the form data, and the other radio input values are ignored. [Here's an example on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_radio). So instead of `value="{{item.checked}}"`, something like `value="[[item.data]]"`.

So the whole thing might be something like

```
class CustomInputComponent extends PolymerElement {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      ratings: {
        type: Array,
        value: function(){ 
          return [
          { id: 1, checked: true, value: 'pie' },
          { id: 2, checked: false, value: 'fries' },
          { id: 3, checked: false, value: 'los dos' }
          ];
        }
      },
      selected: {
        // type: Number or Object, idk
        // Keep track of the selected <input>
      }
    };
  }
  static get template() {
    return html`        
      <p>do you want pie or fries?</p>
      <div id="mydiv">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ratings}}">
          <input 
            type="radio"
            name="testgroup"
            id="[[item.id]]"
            value="[[item.value]]"
            checked="{{item.checked::input}}"
            on-change="radioChanged"
            >[[item.value]]
          </input>
        </template>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  radioChanged(event){
    // update ratings[n].checked for selected input
    // set selected input to currently selected input
  }
}
```